# Cannot resolve type

Tags: java

In my package I have two classes: Animals and Game

The class Game has a method called newGame which requires as paramter two objects of type Animals.

My code is:

```
Game test = new Game();
test.newGame(new Animals("x"), new Animals("y"));
```

However, I get an error telling me it is impossible to resolve type "Animals"... Suggestions?

Comment: 1. did you import Animals in your class ?

Comment: Is it not enough for them to be in the same package?

Comment: probably unrelated, but you are calling newGame() as static method on Game - is this a typo? There is also missing a parenthesis, so I wonder if this is the actual code you posted ... It would also be good to copy&paste the complete full error message from the compiler

Comment: Hi, Sorry the parenthesis was a copy/paste mistake. The error is " Cannot instantiate the type Animal"

Comment: @Andreas yes, sorry, that was a typo.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing enough code (what do your `Game` and `Animal` classes look like), it is hard to say whether you are creating `Animal` objects properly. However, I can say that the line

```
Game.newGame(new Animals("x"), new Animals("y");
```

is a syntax error. You are missing a closing right bracket on the right side of the line.

Answer (score 3):

You need to close your parenthesis.

```
Game.newGame(new Animals("x"), new Animals("y"));
                                               ^
```

Also, if you have the class "Animals" inside of a different package, you need to import "Animals" from that package with an import statement.

```
import packagename.Animals;
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something to do with ambiguity in constructors of Animals class? 
A more detailed error message will help.